# Push machine learning models from Filestore to Azure data factory

Tags: python, azure, pickle, databricks

I built a linear regression model.

```
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I know that I am able to store the models by doing something similar to:

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_name="LR Model") as run:
  mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model", input_example=X_train[:5])
  mlflow.log_metric("mse", mean_squared_error(y_test, lr.predict(X_test)))
```

but that is not my intention.

I want to be able to move the pickle file to Azure data lake so I stored it in the Filestore using:

```
import pickle
filename = '/dbfs/FileStore/lr_model.pkl'
pickle.dump(lr, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

I am now trying to push the pickle file from filestore in databricks to Azure data lake. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current versions of Data bricks do not allow transfer of non-notebook files out of Databricks. Hopefully, incoming versions will proffer a solution to this.

Comment: You can really export model to outside of the Databricks. For example, it could be done using `dbutils.fs.cp` or something like this - it depends on if data lake is mounted or not